# How do I write a SqlCommand that selects top 3 most repeated values in a column in ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve the most sold items from a date picker "from-to" format. I have this `SqlCommand` I am trying to run but its not working.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 3 Sold COUNT(Sold) AS MOST_FREQUENT FROM Transactions GROUP BY Sold ORDER BY COUNT(Sold) DESC WHERE Dates Between'" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text) + "' and '" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text) + "'", con);
```

Updated

```
("SELECT TOP 3 Sold, COUNT(Sold) AS MOST_FREQUENT FROM Transactions GROUP BY Sold WHERE Dates Between '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)+"' and '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text)+"' ORDER BY COUNT(Sold) DESC", con);
```

Update 2 full code

```
protected void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POS_SystemConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        if (txtDate.Text != null && txtDate2.Text != null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 3 Sold, COUNT(Sold) AS MOST_FREQUENT FROM Transactions WHERE Sold GROUP BY Dates Between '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)+"' and '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text)+"' ORDER BY COUNT(Sold) DESC", con);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You a syntax error missing comma (,) after `SOLD` column in Select list and also move the order by clause in the end and where clause before Group by like this:

Order of clauses should be SELECT, WHERE, GROUP BY, Order by

```
protected void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POS_SystemConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                if (txtDate.Text != null && txtDate2.Text != null)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 3 Sold, COUNT(Sold) AS MOST_FREQUENT FROM Transactions WHERE Dates Between '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)+"' and '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text)+"'  GROUP BY Sold ORDER BY COUNT(Sold) DESC", con);

                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }


                }

                con.Close();

            }
```

Also, you must use parameterized queries instead of concatenating the parameter values inline to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: I get incorrect syntax  near where.  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.'"

Comment: Just add a comma (,) after `Sold` column in `SELECT` clause `SELECT TOP 3 Sold, Count(Sold).` and move order by after where clause. Check updated answer

Comment: Please update the question with error that you are getting. Also, what is the generated sql query after appending from and to dates?

Comment: The `where` clause should appear before the `group by`. Swap them, everything else should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 3 Sold, COUNT(Sold) AS MOST_FREQUENT FROM Transactions WHERE Dates Between '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)+"' and '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text)+"' GROUP BY Sold ORDER BY COUNT(Sold) DESC

Group by and order by should be after where clause.